# A manually installed SEH doesn't work in inner blocks

Tags: c, winapi, seh

After reading  [The Crash Course](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0197/exception/exception.aspx)
and a few posts here, I've implemented a very basic version.
My only requirement is to able to "catch" any exception (only 'Win32', as I don't throw/raise any) 
and Exit the thread that raised it.
I have a properly prototyped function that just calls 'ExitThread', and an 'EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION' struct that has it in it's handler property, and the actual previous handle in the previous property.
What I do to set this handler is calling:

```
BOOL set_my_handler(){
EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION* p_excep = &excep // excep is a global static EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION
__asm{
      mov EAX, p_excep
      mov FS:[0],EAX
 }
 ...
 }
```

**The Problem:**
when I cause an exception (say by:

```
* (dword*) 0 = 0;)
```

in the same scope that I called set_my_handler,
my handler is called as expected. But,  if I cause the same exception in an inner block, by calling a function that does it, it's just doesn't work. I get the Unhandled Exception messagebox.
while debugging, I've noticed that FS:[0] remains the same (pointing to my handler) in the inner function.
BTW, I'm not using any (try/catch or try/_except in my code)

I appreciate your help, thanks.

**The Answer to my problem** (thanks to *Raymond Chen*):
It turns out that exception registration entities must be allocated on the stack, as there's a security mechanism that verifies its location against the stack segment registers.

Comment: Installing an exception handler is more than just hooking into fs:[0]. For security reasons, exception registrations must be on the stack. More details [here](http://jpassing.com/2008/05/20/fun-with-low-level-seh/).